# Return variables to web server from PayPal Express Checkout Client REST API

Tags: django, paypal

I am using PayPal Express Checkout Client sided REST API javascript and Django 2.0.x/Python views for an ecommerce site. I have been able to implement Express Checkout and have the customer redirected to a success page on my server through the onAuthorize function. I need to access the paypal old IPN style listener variables or equivalent ... custom, mc_fee, email, first_name, last_name from paypal. I have no idea how to do this with the new REST API.

Is this processed through a webhook and if so how? Example code?

I just need the above variables returned back to my server preferably in my views.py checkout_complete function.

Thanks

mmbella